# Show git contributions from GitLab account on my GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I worked a summer job as a software developer for which I was given a git account to use (my own email on the company's domain), and that repository was saved on GitLab. I had TONS of contributions on that which I would like to be shown on my GitHub account. Is it possible to show that?

I have tried adding the git email to my GitHub account, but that did not help (waited >24hrs).

Please let me know if there is a possibility of me being able to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can upload your GitLab repos to GitHub. Commits with timestamps from previous days will show up on your heatmap. You can do this by creating a repository on GitHub without a README, so that your original repo's `.git` directory is preserved when you push it upstream. Otherwise, all your timestamps won't be saved, and the entire repo will look like one big commit on the day you upload it.

For contributions to GitLab repos you don't own, you could try uploading the fork you've created for it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I am not the owner of the repo as I was just a contributor to my coworker's repo. I don't think what you said will work for my case, or will it?

Comment: Try mirroring the repository if uploading your fork doesn't work.